# Fill Enum in function Python

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe, enums

somehow I have problems to fill an enum into my function. Somehow I receive the following error message:

> line 22, in SetRevenueScenarios
>       self.Scenarios[len(self.Scenarios.keys())] = data
>
> AttributeError: 'Market' object has no attribute 'Scenarios'

The goal of the code is to fill in the repeating revenues into a pandas dataframe. The function used should fill once the revenues and identify it with an enum for the dedicted BU.

```
import csv
from enum import Enum
import pandas as pd

class EmpID(Enum):
    TVs = 1
    Camera = 2
    Computers = 3
    Jeans = 4
    Jacket = 5
    Meat = 6


class Market(object):

    def SetEmployerID(self, empID):
        self.empID = empID

    def SetRevenueScenarios(self, past_revenues, Enum):
        data = pd.Series(past_revenues)
        data = data.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
        self.Scenarios[len(self.Scenarios.keys())] = data               

    def GetEmployerID(self):
        return self.empID

    def GetRevenueScenarios(self, scenario_number):
        return self.Scenarios[scenario_number]

#---------------------------------------------------------------

def read_csv(filename):
    market_dict = dict()

    with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')       
        for column in reader:

            if column[0] == "EmpID":
                mark = Market()
                mark.SetEmployerID(column[1])

            if column[0] == "Area":
                if column[1] == "Electronic_TVs": 
                    mark.SetRevenueScenarios(column[1:],EmpID.TVs)

                market_dict[mark.GetEmployerID()] = mark


    return market_dict

#---------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
  market_list=read_csv('C:Filiale.TXT')

  for BM_id in market_list:
      print(market_list[BM_id].GetEmployerID())
```

The input file looks like:

```
EmpID;Martin
Area;Electronic_TVs
BU;TVs
Revenues;100;300;1000;4000;20000;300000
Area;Electronic_Computers
BU;Computers
Revenues;300;600;4000;8000;200000;3000000
Area;Clothes_Jeans
BU;Jeans
Revenues;10;30;10000;40000;100000;2000000
EmpID;James
Area;Food_Meat
BU;Meat
Revenues;100;300;10;40;20;30
```

Comment: Where are you initializing `Market.Scenarios`?

Comment: You will likely need a `Market.__init__()` that initialises `self.Scenarios = []`

Answer (score 1):

that error message is correct. your Market class has no Scenarios attribute, but you're trying to access one here:

```
self.Scenarios[len(self.Scenarios.keys())]
```

did you forget to define it in a constructor?

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to initialise it. But how can I use for the getters function the enumerator to call the function?

Comment: @MCM that part of your program is not clear. what is the purpose of the Enum in this code? how is it being used in the different functions? is the enum (named EmpId?) in your code associated with a Revenue Scenario?

Comment: Yes Every Scenario should get the enum number. When I call the function I can only call the revenue scenario of interest. It is better then defining for every scenario a seperate function